# Could some of our conceptions about the physical universe be wrong?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, scientific-method, thought-experiment

I managed to create cold fission by placing a carbon crucible into a polysyrene cut out, put a few small sticks of glow stick stuff from the dollar store, put the lid on and generated a 5 meter field with both negative and positive polarities and videoed it and sent it to multiple people. Light also effected this contraption. I also have managed to reduce the mass or increase the mass of this contraption and measure it using wood planks. Please review the following experimentation results and denial of truth. There have been several attempts to try and silence me on this subject and I have no idea why: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/306649/has-anyone-tried-to-simulate-an-atomic-structure-using-electromagnets-and-curren

Would you rather stay on earth than travel faster than the speed of light and reach sirius in a matter of no time?

I believe that our current view of the universe is inconsistent with the scientific method due to the fact that evidence is being directly ignored with two seperate fundamentle principals being created to explain the clearly presented conclusive evidence, and that there must be previous misconceptions in the scientific models when some of the deductions were made to cause this phenomena. Causing some of the evidence produced in the modern age to being falsified due to inaccuracies with calculations based on characteristics of interactions within specific scenarios rather than any physical evidence. Assumptions could include the fact that we thought an atom was the smallest particle until subatomic particles were found, and we thought those were the smallest possible particle until quarks were found and their constituants were theorized.

Perhaps stating that the conclusion that has been arrived at is one of various different possibilities when something has not been proven conclusively and quantifying that fact using a value?

I reference the following theory as proof on this in a way to help theorize on how to improve the accuracies of the scientific method.

Comment: I'm not sure if I quite understand the question - I mean the body of the text rather than the title; however there is no consensus opinion on what Dark Energy or Dark Matter is, so it seems quite likely that this is the case; though, I should add, not 'wrong', but rather incomplete.

Comment: This question is shorter than the linked one but almost as incomprehensible. The answer to the title question is "most definitely". "Evidence is being directly ignored with two seperate fundamentle principals being created to explain" or "Causing some of the evidence produced in the modern age to being falsified due to inaccuracies with calculations based on characteristics of interactions" are completely obscure. As is this is not an SE answerable question, if it is a question. Pick an example of what you are talking about, a short one, and illustrate your criticisms on it.

Comment: I am basically trying to verify all past assertions going back hundreds of years using more conclusive and logical reasoning based on current experimental and observational evidence and checking to see how I can proove or falsify something with more strength so was curious on what everyone elses opinions on the weaknesses of the current deductive reasoning methods are.

Comment: @goldberg: thats a hell of a job, I don't think Feynman or Einstein did as much; good luck!

Comment: Ok, but that is not a question, it is a research program. What do you want us to answer here (and remember about size constraints)?

Comment: Perhaps in the theory we could give a value to how would we determine if something is conclusive or it is one of many possibilities and account for that in our current scientific model?

Comment: P.S. I am saying all this because I have had a moment of clarity where I believe I could visualize the nature of ElectroMagnetic energy and want to verify if my visualization is true or not after a decade of researching the subject, having concrete beliefs in the current atomic and cosmic models and instantly revising my opinion.

Comment: I also want to note I can build circuit boards, computer systems, program the computer system in over 10 computer languages, program the circuit board in native code, design Arc Furnace systems, generally got 90%-100% on average for my mathematics education, understand the concepts to design a magnetron sputter coater and am in the process of sourcing materials to fabricate and automate them with a boilermaker and various other skills so even though my views do not match the current scientific model, it does not mean that I am not educated in it or uneducated/ignorant.

Comment: @Mozibur Ullah, I just went to Einsteins relativity model and went through all the equations to see where he sourced his equasions and the logic he used, then the logic the person before him used, then the logic before that person etc until I have validated an assumption (I believe that before Einstein, we did not understand that a Neutron was a fragment of energy with two symetrical but opposite poles and charges, or that every collective mass inherantly has an electromagnetic ionosphere (atoms, buildings, people, the planet, the solar system, cosmic clusters etc.) including polarization

Comment: It sounds like you may want to look at [underdetermination of scientific theories](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-underdetermination).  There is no such thing as "visualization of the nature" being true or not, science does not study "natures", it studies empirical relations only. It would be an intuitive interpretation, useful or not, but there can be plenty of those, all consistent with experiments.

Comment: Feynman said that the best bit of scientific advice is to say everything was made of atoms; a more modern take on it is to say that everything is made up of light; actually there is a basic distinction between matter (fermions) and light (bosons); but with super-symmetry, they're in a sense the same; of course, no-ones found supersymmetry, but its a nice idea all the same.

Comment: @Conifold I also agree with this, however I believe that things are limited to what we can actually observe and cannot be explained with the unobservable or imagined scenarios to generate a conclusive determination (like looking through software code and debugging each line to conclusively determine the logic misconception I have had or another programmer has had due to the analysis of log files).

Without an observable result the theory is basically speculation to me and the only thing valid is the mathematical description of the characteristics.

Comment: I conclude that the premise of Feynmann quoted is fallible due to subatomic particles, and that we can only conclude that we can only observe spacetime with a certain degree of accuracy due to the limitations on our biology and technology.

Comment: Since you said that you want to test each assumption by going back; you should go really back by reading some history of science...try looking up Lucretious; to be honest, I don't Feynman knew this, otherwise he certainly would have said this in his *lectures*.

Comment: This sounds like the programme of empiricists like Mach, and later logical positivists. It was pursued at length, but ultimately abandoned as counterproductive.  As it turned out, after Popper, Quine and Kuhn, all of scientific theory is "basically speculation", including the "observable results", the distinction is mostly pragmatic. On the other hand, theoretical fictions play a highly productive role in organizing predictions and inventing new theories, so there is not much point left to such artificial "debugging" either.

Comment: I am not concluding that scientific progress be halted by theories, however I am concluding that the Mathematic determination of things would bring a higher level of accuracy with previous constants and equations being analyzed after comprehension of new information to mitigate invalid falsification of evidence.

Comment: Mathematical determination of things is itself replete with building theoretical fictions, just look at algebraic geometry with its stacks, topoi, sheaves, etc., and their extensive use in quantum physics. In fact, the process is analogous to physics. And it is not controversial that physical theories can ideally benefit from mathematical precision, indeed this is one of the drives behind string theory. Older theories are already constantly reanalyzed in the light of new developments, and reinterpreted in the modernized language, just look at symplectic geometry view of classical mechanics.

Comment: @conifold: whats a stack?

Comment: @MoziburUllah [Algebraic stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(mathematics)), an intricate concept, but one of Grothendieck's masterpieces. Designed to study classes ("moduli spaces") where objects, and their families, possess symmetries that vary across the class. Currently extensively used in mathematics of string theory, where the objects are open and closed strings.

Comment: It's not so intricate when thought about it in the right way: for example as a categorification of a sheaf: instead of a sheaf being valued in sets, its valued in categories, usually groupoids; it's intricate when you have to work with them though, for sure.

Comment: I have had to deal with a few life priorities and am in the process of reading the works linked to me, however I want to pose to you the following to demonstrate that the same principals must apply to both the large scale and the small scale (Brownian Diffusion or Brownian Motion): if we dropped something that we could see with the naked eye that could not fly and was dead (such as a flea or a dust particle) in the upper atmosphere with gravity, how long would it take to reach terminal felocity or would the laws of quantum mechanics effect it (Basically same as brownian diffussion principal).

Comment: I also want to note that you can look at a graph (it doesn't matter how many vectors there are) and take measurements of the axes to derive equations, and is what I suggest when dealing with the unknown. Constants can be used to represent unknown forces and calculations can be modified when those forces have been realized. Hypothetical scenarios can be thought of and tested to verify if those scenarios could be possible, however at the core of it is the measured observations.

Comment: Another notion to help cement the nature of energy in terms of the big bang or any other creation principal. Does brownian diffusion not happen in cosmological levels due to the sheer size and force of the electromagnetic fields? If matter was broken down to the tiniest of levels and spread in an undistributed manner would brownian motion cause formations of bigger electromagnetic fields until the fields were big enough to polarize other fields they share a field with?

Comment: I think I finally have proven that gravity is a result of polarization, as is dark energy and matter. Please take note of how your theory gives way to experimental evidence.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your title question would be an unequivocal "yes."  Its absolutely possible that some of our conceptions about the physical universe may be wrong.  In fact, I believe that most scientists are rather confident that some of our conceptions are wrong.

However, the goal of rectifying this issue may be out of scope of mere mortals.  One famous phrasing of the issue is the [Münchhausen trilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCnchhausen_trilemma).  It argues that all efforts to "prove" anything logically must end in one or more of the following:

- The circular argument, in which theory and proof support each other
- The regressive argument, in which each proof requires a further proof, ad infinitum
- The axiomatic argument, which rests on accepted precepts

While the trilemma, paradoxically, cannot be proven, it is worth considering as a point of discourse.  Science has traditionally been very adverse to circular arguments.  Regressive arguments would be literally infinitely difficult to prove out in a human lifetime.  That leaves axiomatic arguments.  However, for what you seek to prove, the question of "what is an acceptable axiom" is difficult.  Your whole goal is to uproot any assumptions your predecessors may have made.  What is "good enough" for assuming an axiom?

You may have more luck taking up the age old approach of science.  In the comments you mention having a visualization of electromagnetism that you have refined for a while.  Can you use that approach to identify tests that can be done to distinguish your visualization from the currently accepted scientific cannon?  If there are such tests, are they tests you can perform?

If you cannot perform the tests needed to distinguish them (perhaps they call for a particle accelerator), that may form a seed from which you can engage in the unraveling process you describe.  Perhaps you can find questionable assumptions which have been made which would influence someone's decision regarding "which model is best."  That assumption might be testable.

Do remember that science is designed to falsify hypotheses.  It never actually states what is "true," but rather is merely a very powerful approach for weeding out weak hypotheses through experimentation.  Just because there is a standard way of looking at things does not mean it is the only way.  However, do realize that the "standard way of looking at things" is heavily beaten on by thousands upon thousands of scientists.  You may find that your approach has been effective for you merely because it has not been tested as hard.  Or you may find that your approach is actually just a rephrasing of the current standard theory, in which case it is equally valid.

Comment: I totally agree and have been coming up with several thought experiments, which I have investigated and am designing in order to try and falsify this theory. I also believe this theory is built upon all current and previous knowledge of science in order to explain descrepancies between calculations and perceptions and rectify the difference.

Comment: Proven http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/40592/a-note-to-those-who-try-falsify-fact-with-theory 
I also assume you know about this now: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xWfeE7l1Wxo

Comment: Cort ammon, I have proven light is a variable condition with my experimentation that you can reproduce for $10 at home. The speed of light was broken by NASA recently. Just try make the conditions I said. Additionally I have videos antigravity and cold fission and sent it through to various researchers, my friends colleagues at NASA, I tweeted the formula to Elon Musk with the cold fission reactor design, contacted a university (Of which I am an Alumni) as well as various other measures. Your attempt to discredit me is miserable and please stop messaging me in chat.

Comment: Read the peer reviewed paper published by NASA before you open your mouth about string theory or any other unmovable theory to try discredit me and show your ignorance and belief in the mystical such as the recently falsified string theory rather than reproducible, recorded factual evidence that has been open sourced to the greater community.

Comment: @GregGoldberg What I am trying to do is most definitely not trying to discredit you.   In fact, you will find I am giving you far more benefit of the doubt than most people will.  If you think this is trying to discredit you, wait until you see what people who actually try to discredit you will do.  Those people will be far less kind than I have been.  To be honest, given the quality of the content of your claims, I have been downright cordial.  I've even avoided correcting your attempts to put words in my mouth regarding what I believe and do not believe.

Comment: Sorry Cort, that was directed at someone else which keeps messaging me with a similar name and I have been extremely busy documenting and generating models in AutoCAD, generating experimental recordings etc. The reason for lack of the quality of my content is due to the fact that I thought I should let everyone know as soon as possible that my easy tests seem to defy the logic of universal constants.